# layout shifts - CSS problem

Tags: html, css, layout

I am  coding this layout as a wordpress theme and having a slight problem

This is a [link to my index page](https://dl.getdropbox.com/u/750932/wordpress.htm) and how the layout should be,

however, after adding comments and a comment form, [the layout shifts](https://dl.getdropbox.com/u/750932/hello-world.htm) to the left a bit.

I am pretty sure it has to do with the comments or comment form because when I delete the code to include the comment.php file from the page, the layout doesnt shift to the left

this happens in IE, firefox and Chrome on Windows 7
screen resolution 1680x1050

Comment: The link to: **link to my index page**, is not working

Comment: The "**the layout shifts**" link not working too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because of the vertical scroll bar that appears to the right. Because your page is centered, the scroll bar reduces the horizontal visible area, causing your layout to shift a bit to the left.

Comment: alright thank makes sense, i guess ill make the index page longer

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the long page is causing a scroll bar to appear on the right side of your browser. And this causes everything to be shifted left. At least, this is what was causing it for me, and it makes sense that would be the reason.

Sometimes its the simple things...